# Невозможность обратиться к динамически загруженному элементу.

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Не могу понять, почему не получается обратиться к уже существующему динамически загруженному элементу.

После ajax-запроса загружается форма, потом по нажатию кнопки в форме снова выполняется запрос (перезагрузка формы не происходит), и должно поменяется содержимое элемента MessageField в этой форме, а возникает ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Файл index:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Block"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Request(Mode)
    {
        jQuery.ajax
        ({
            url:        "Script.php",
            type:       "POST",
            dataType:   "html",
            data:       "Mode=" + Mode,
            success:    function(responce)
                        {
                            if (responce == '1')
                            {
                                document.getElementById("MessageField").innerHTML = 
                                "Message text";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                document.getElementById("Block").innerHTML = responce;
                            }
                        },
            error:      document.getElementById("Block").innerHTML = "Request error."       
        });
    }
    Request("load form");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Скрипт, которому посылается ajax-запрос:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['Mode'] == 'load form')
    echo
    "
        <form id = 'AuthForm' method = 'post' action = ''>
            <table border = 1>
                <tr>
                    <td id = 'MessageField'>
                        &nbsp
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type = 'submit' name='B1' id='B1' value='Show message'
                        onclick = 'Request()'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    ";
else echo "1";
?>
```

Что не так?

Comment: А если убрать пробелы между знаком равно и атрибутами в html формы?

Comment: Никаких изменений.

Answer (score 1):

Эммм, что то не понятно..

1. Аякс запрос. Допустим, что data: {mode: "load form"}
2. Php возвращает html-форму
3. Затем случается"success:" и вставляет форму в "Block"
4. Дальше ты производишь клик по кнопке
5. Новый Аякс запрос
6. php на этот раз возвращает "1"
7. но ничего не пишется?

Т.е. проблема в том, что не document.getElementById("MessageField") не определен, getElementById не может получить доступ к этому элементу, поскольку он создан динамически.

Правильно ли я понял проблему?

Comment: Ну да, в 7-ом пункте случается "error:", в div "Block" записывается "Request error.", и в консоли JS - жалоба, что "MessageField" не существует.

А вот причину проблемы с document.getElementById("MessageField") мне и хотелось бы понять.